# Can I use (LaTeX?) packages from CTAN in plain TeX?

Tags: macros, miktex, plain-tex, ctan, learning

I have the following assumptions:

- TeX is a kind of language
- Plain TeX is the original environment for this language
- LaTeX (and other environments) is a set of compiled macros written using TeX primitives.
- Lets say MikTeX can organize those macros in local repository so I can reuse them in my LaTeX document.

But I am still not sure if CTAN contains packages for LaTeX or for TeX. Are they written using built-in LaTeX macros or written in pure TeX. If the second is true can I use those packages in plain TeX using `\input`? How should I organize macros from CTAN just download and put into the same folder with my document? Is there any package manager for plain TeX?

Comment: Try to use `\usepackage{foo}` in a plain TeX file ;-) You could use `\input` (a TeX primitive) but then you would get into troubles with `\NeedsTeXFormat`, `\ProvidesPackage` and all the LaTeX specific commands. But I am sure that there are some 'packages' designed for  plain TeX on CTAN

Comment: Ok. So CTAN is mostly for LaTeX only. Those macros are written using LaTeX built-in macros. I didn't find CTAN said it is for LaTeX only so I thought as you say some packages (geometry for example) were written to be used in TeX as well.

Comment: No, CTAN is not LaTeX only. I just don't know any plain TeX 'packages'

Comment: I see. But don't you know if some environment exists for plain TeX but with  support of package management?

Comment: Druid, no, I am sorry, I can't give you an answer about that.

Comment: opmac is a plain 'package'. it's available on ctan. ctan is for all tex-related software and documentation. it's not latex-specific. plain has no support for package management other than `\input`, but this has proven to be enough. after all, a package is only a tex file that is `\input`.

Comment: ctan is not latex-only but the directory `tex/latex` on ctan is for macros that are designed for latex, but there are lots of other directories on the archive.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In short: Plain TeX and LaTeX are different macro packages that define different formats. So, in general, it is *not* possible to use LaTeX packages on top of Plain TeX. For a short introduction to all this rather specialized jargon you may check [this blog post](http://www.seanallred.com/tex/2015/05/25/tex-terminology.html)

It is possible to use some LaTeX packages on Plain TeX (graphics, color and hyperref, for instance), by faking some functionality of LaTeX; only that necessary to load and make the packages operative. Yet another macro package built on top of plain, eplain, has a  built-in ability to load some basic LaTeX macro packages.

```
\beginpackages
  \usepackage{graphicx,color}
  \usepackage{url}
\endpackages
```

It is also possible to use some Plain TeX functionality in LaTeX documents with the `plain` package and the `plain` environment provided. Still, it's not the whole thing, but works for many things.

```
\usepackage{plain}
\begin{plain}
[plain stuff]
\end{plain}
```

You can find all this stuff in CTAN, which contains lots of thing TeX related. Beware though that you need to learn how to navigate in the tex-archive tree.

The MikTeX package manager deals mostly with LaTeX packages, so you may need to learn how to install Plain macro files manually.

Comment: @Druid OPmac is plain TeX package which implements basic LaTeX features but keeps your code straightforward, simple and compact. You needn't a "combo", because hyperlinks and colors (and much more) is implemented. See http://petr.olsak.net/opmac-letak.pdf

Comment: @Lusr56 Sorry, OPmac users needn't msfss because font selection system with OPmac is much more simple and comfortable. We needn't combo. And OPmac supports foreign languages. Please, don't judge something what is unknown for you.

Comment: @Lusr56 \textbf{bold \textit{italics}} -> {\bf bold {\em italics}}, see the middle of page three in the English documentation. Languages switchers must be hardcoded into format, because hyphenation patterns are hardcoded into format too (it is TeX feature).  OPmac works with both: csplain and plain based on etex.src. And the markup is simply plain TeX markup. Of course, it is not LaTeX markup. Users can modify the markup by their macros. If we are talking about missing LaTeX markup then the advice is simple: use LaTeX, don't use plain.

Comment: Original question was about packages on Plain. OPmac is an example. LaTeX packages on Plain is nonsense, IMHO. And you started with alternatives to LaTeX in Plain when you mentioned a combo.

Comment: ad 1. Of course, if I change plain TeX to a pseudo LaTeX using miniltx then some LaTeX packages work. Ad 2. Users are using plain TeX because LaTeX markup is very uncomfortable for them so your notes are irrelevant. Ad 3. OPmac is a part of csplain package, so ams-math.tex is installed when OPmac is used. But OPmac works on top with classical TeX, pdftex, xetex, luatex. Try `tex opmac-u-en` or `pdftex opmac-u-en`. Ad 4. Multiple columns: use \begmulti...\endmulti, read page 6 below of English documentation.

Comment: Finally: this discussion is absolutely off topic here. Please, use my email if you have questions about OPmac. And don't put lies about OPmac here.

Comment: Because you continuously put lies about OPmac here, I must response, sorry. Ad 1. No, opmac needs only one file ams-math.tex from csplain package. It doesn't need csplain as format. OPmac doesn't need any extra fonts. Ad 2. OPmac doesn't defines peculiar markup, it respect the plain TeX markup. If somebody like LaTeX markup (I don't), then he/she will use LaTeX. Ad 3. I will not use chat. You can use my email for communication. This is more private.

Comment: @Druid OPmac requires the csfonts, amsfonts, rsfs, and ecfonts required by ams-math.tex, a file required by opmac.tex; both macro files are distributed in the csplain package on MikTeX. OPmac provides commands for page layout, chapters, sections, bibliographic references, indexes and the like; so it defines its own markup language, fairly different from LaTeX's. So it's not really flat Plain; i.e. the Plain TeX with the standard cm fonts. Don't worry: if you want to try it, the Miktex package manager should take care of all these dependencies.

Answer (score 4):

This is only a partial answer, as it does not provide the full requested information.

There are macro bundles ('packages') on CTAN designed for PlainTeX,
listed under [CTAN archive](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros) and explicitly stated as such, e.g.

- http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/eplain
- http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/inrstex

etc.

The directory [CTAN plain/contrib](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/plain/contrib) archive contains a lot of user contributions as TeX bundles.

The direct usage of `LaTeX` macros in PlainTeX is difficult, depends on their complexity to bypass the LaTeX style and boil them down to TeX. Either it's necessary to copy the macros out of the LaTeX package or to use some `\let\RequirePackage` ... etc stuff to calm down TeX.

I doubt that the whole effort to `\input` LaTeX packages/source files/preambles will gain any profit.

The screen shots just show some of the macro directories in the relevant categories. The overview isn't meant to be complete.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: your list stops just before the `plain` subdirectory.  that contains a further subdirectory `contrib` that is full of possibilities.

Comment: Oh great. It basically answers my question

Comment: @barbarabeeton: I wasn't finished yet.. I thought about another screen shot

Comment: @ChristianHupfer -- i'm too lazy to pull this up on a browser; i keep a local copy of the ctan FILES.byname for reference, and refresh it about once a month.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Your comment indicates that I am not clever enough to do this as well? ;-) I have no account on 'comedy' and a I don't want to clone CTAN on a local disk here

Comment: It turns out at least MiKTeX contains Knuth's macros. And also a few from that folder are available in a package manager. So when I use \input they are visible by a compiler

Comment: @Druid: Yes, but not the LaTeX packages of course -- they are indigestible for TeX ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer -- no, i'm sure you are quite able to do what i've done.  there are many ways to find out what's contained on ctan.  the FILES.byname file is by no means a clone; it's simply a directory list of the current contents, that is updated nightly by the ctan management procedures.  i find that it's a quick way to check whether a file i'm looking for (or at) has a later version, or in fact whether it's on ctan at all.  i just didn't think it was worth posting it as an answer, so i chose to add a comment to your quite acceptable answer.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer -- the only problem i have with your answer is that it's not necessarily obvious that either list shows only one screen from the browser; there's actually quite a bit more.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: I was just **too** lazy to show multiple screen shots. I linked the (most important?) directory as well.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer -- thanks for the additions.  i think it's worth making it clear that plain tex is still actively in use, although the practitioners are not as visible as those using latex.  the original question cast serious doubt on that, although i see now that more clarifying comments have appeared.

Answer (score 4):

CTAN is a TeX & friends-related code repository not a LaTeX snob :P.  The contents are separated for convenience and maintenance plus a few esoteric details (as far as I know). For example if you look at your MikTeX directory you can see this separation clearly. Because packages are also installed based on this structure.

But possibility of using a LaTeX package in plain TeX is up to the author of the package. If you use LaTeX constructs in your package and some plain TeX user wants to use it, then it will fail as the LaTeX macros won't be available. If you use `\newcommand` instead of `\def` or other LaTeX constructs like `\newcounter` and so on then plain TeX user needs to either import the latex style file with input which would be more or less using LaTeX hence futile or rewrite the macros from scratch.

Some authors actually check the compilation engine, branch off and decide accordingly during the package import.